# Obtener en Java desde un Map un Set con elementos únicos

Tags: java, map

Tengo el siguiente `Map<String, Set<String>>`:

`{upload=[ADMIN], configure.accounts=[ADMIN, CONSULT], consult=[ADMIN, CONSULT], configure.merchants=[MANAGER, ADMIN], configure.invoices=[MANAGER, ADMIN], graphics=[MANAGER, ADMIN]}`

y quiero obtener una estructura `Set<String>` como la siguiente:

`[ADMIN, CONSULT, MANAGER]`

donde los datos están filtrados obteniendo todos los valores posibles del Set dentro del Map. Esto lo puedo realizar recorriendo el mapa y comparando los valores para que agregue aquellos que no están dentro del `Set`, ¿existe alguna función para hacer esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podemos obtener una colección de sets a partir del mapa usando el método `values()` de la interfase Map. Después de esto, podemos iterar la colección devuelta y agregar todos los elementos de cada uno de los sets de la colección al set que te interesa obtener como resultado. El código quedaría más o menos como lo siguiente:

```
Set<String> resultingSet = new HashSet<String>();
Collection<Set<String>> collectionOfSets = map.values();
for (Set<String> s : collectionOfSets) {
    resultingSet.addAll(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En java 8 se puede solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```
Set<String> resultingSet = map.values().stream().flatMap(t -> t.stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```